# Issue when indexing named range with more than one section

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to link data from one workbook to another, 
I set up a named range with 3 sections in the other workbook and trying to index it.
the 3 at end of formula refers to the 3rd section of the range.

=INDEX(test.xlsm'!Named_range,1,1,3)

The formula does work and gets me the correct value however it only seems to work when the other sheet is open.
if I close both workbooks and reopen the one I am linking the data to it results in a REF error and can't find the range in the other workbook. When I open the other workbook where I linked it from then it works.

Also if I put the named range as 1 section it works but the issue here is I am trying to do this with a range that has 3 sections.

is it possible to make this work without having both workbooks open?

Comment: another **sheet** or another **work book** ??

Comment: Meant to say 2 dif workbooks, I will correct the question

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: You can try making 3 named ranges and use CHOOSE: `=INDEX(CHOOSE(3,test.xlsm'!Named_range_1,test.xlsm'!Named_range_2,test.xlsm'!Named_range_3),1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a fully qualified file name for the workbook, including the drive and folder. INDEX() can then access the values in the closed workbook...

```
=INDEX('G:\test\test.xlsm'!MyRange,1,1)
```

Comment: when I close the workbook and open it, it does change it to a full file name like you have there. It still shows up with a REF error

Comment: Get rid of the "3" at the end of your formula.

Comment: I guess my real question is it possible to do this when a range is in a few sections? it seems like it only works when the range is 1 section

Comment: @ExcelHero Welcome Back!  Nothing like a 4 and half year hiatus in answering questions.

Comment: Please show me the definition of the Named Range as specified in the Name Manager.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Lol

Comment: @ExcelHero can you please be more clear what you want? what do you mean by definition     it refers to          =sheet1!$AM$58:$AM$62,sheet1!$AO$58:$AO$62,sheet!$BT$58:$CC$62

Comment: doesn't have to do with the name or the range it had to do with the fact that the range has sections. it works perfectly if only one section

Comment: @atgold18   The correct term is AREAS, not sections. And yes, that is exactly why I wanted to see the definition of your named range. I am still interested in seeing if I can get this to work for you if you will provide the definition.

Comment: what do you mean by definition? does it matter what its called? let's say that i named it named_range as the definition

Comment: No. In the Name Manager (Ctrl-F3 from the worksheet) select the name and copy the contents of the Refers To field. That is the definition of the name.

Comment: didn't I say in the above comment? =sheet1!$AM$58:$AM$62,sheet1!$AO$58:$AO$62,sheet!$BT$58:$CC$62